# Boss is skeptical of using a version control system for new project, should I anyway?

Tags: version-control

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109817/superior-refusing-to-use-subversion

My question is similar, but here are the main differences in my scenario:

- We are starting a new project from scratch, using PHP and web tech. There would be no down time in development as we would be adopting it from the beginning, if I have my way.
- My dev team consists of me, and my boss. We are the "IT" Department of a relatively small firm.

The web app will replace a legacy application with absolutely no source control. Due to variations in geographical legal requirements, the decision was made (before I was hired) to fork the app into 7 completely separate directories for each version. Different developers did different things in different places at different times after that. Patching changes across them, well, I think it could be done better, I guess that's why I'm posting.

My boss's proposal, directly pasted from an email:

> - Updates should be submitted as packages in the SUBMISSIONS folder.  The package should contain all relevant files as well as an
>     ‘UPDATE.NFO’ file that contains a description of the update, a list of
>     all new files included (with descriptions), and a list of all modified
>     files with modification details.
> - Update packages should focus on an individual element and not stray from its intended purpose.  Code should be designed to be modular and
>     reusable whenever possible.
> - All submitted packages should be installed in each developer’s test environment soon after submission.  Each developer is to review the
>     new addition and voice any concerns over its installation to the
>     production environment.  A standard package update should be held for
>     a minimum of 3 business days for this review process before being
>     loaded into the production environment.  High priority updates/fixes
>     can skip this requirement.

The reason source control was invented is to make all that automatic, right? I suggested subversion, because that's what I used in college. Boss doesn't like subversion because "It makes a mess of the code" (i.e. uses binary magic and is not plainly readable). We did try it one time, but I think trying to use it on windows made weird lower/uppercase errors and we couldn't check out our files. I don't know whether it's only subversion, or all source control products that are objectionable.

So, what kind of argument should I make to my boss? Or is he right, and there could be a danger of losing all our work from some weird bug?

Or am I wrong altogether? Is source control really necessary in my situation? This is our main business-critical software we're talking about, so it will end up huge no doubt. But there's only 2 developers (now).

Additionally, If I can't convince him, would there be any point to me using it only for myself? I am speaking as someone with very limited experience actually using svn; all I really know is checkout and commit. What are the features of source control (may include other products than svn) that would aid in my individual development effort?

Please no "get another job" comments. That's not helpful to the debate.

Comment: 'And please no "Get another job" comments.'  Why not? Your boss is doomed.

Comment: Even if you can't convince him, it's still useful to use it privately for yourself. So you can freely edit your files without fear. You have a bunch of "save points" for the files you work on. Even if you have to have SVN on your local box... better than nothing at all.

Comment: @S.Lott, I think the OP has the right to specify the bounds of the question. "Get another job" is not feasible, for instance, if the OP lives in a small country and his/her father-/mother-in-law is the boss of a job in which the OP is paid double or triple what they're worth in the open market. In short, it's not part of the question.

Comment: @Yar: I, on the other hand, think that the OP is being silly in trying to specify the bounds on the *answer*. The question indicates an almost criminal level of liability for failure to adhere to minimal software quality practices.

Comment: @S.Lott Agreed, that's fair. What I'd like to see out of this question is exactly how to achieve the boss' goals using any particular version control system.

Comment: You can look for a new job now, or you can look for one when a horrific disaster occurs and bankrupts the company - and trust me, that WILL happen if you develop your "main business-critical software" with no version control beyond hoping that developers correctly copy files into a folder.

Comment: @Yar: "What I'd like to see out of this question is exactly how to achieve the boss' goals using any particular version control system"?  Why?  That doesn't seem to be what the question asks.  Why does that interest you when that's not the question?  Perhaps you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Regarding SVN, the latest version no longer litters the code with .svn directories.

Comment: @Carson63000, long before source control became common developers were working on large software projects quite successfully simply copying changed files into the correct directory.  Truth is, if success or failure of a project is determined by using source control, then the company needs better programmers.

Comment: @S.Lott: Another way to see it is that the boss is a boss of a small firm, thus inexperienced, and the OP stands a chance of not only creating a good impression but also benefiting the company's growth if he can convince his/her boss well.

Comment: @S.Lott `I, on the other hand, think that the OP is being silly in trying to specify the bounds on the answer....`
Well, the specific bound is not silly at all. Career advice is off topic, and although an answer that would answer the question and offer career advice is perfectly fine by me, I don't think it's _silly_ for OP to specify that (s)he doesn't care for career advice.

Comment: @S.Lott What I do find silly on the other hand, is career advice in itself, especially when it's "look for another job". There are so many unknown variables, that I find it impossible to take any such advice seriously.

Comment: @Nav: Another way to see it is that the boss is ruining the small firm, and the inexperience cannot possibly be rectified by the OP before the firm goes out of business.

Comment: @YannisRizos: "Career advice is off topic".  Therefore, repeating that they don't care for career advice is a total waste of bandwidth.  And explaining (again) that's it's off topic would be yet a larger waste of bandwidth, right?  Or.  Perhaps career advice is the only workable advice in this case.

Comment: @S.Lott `Therefore, repeating that they don't care for career advice is a total waste of bandwidth.` Agreed. In that sense, it's silly.

Comment: Sounds exactly like my last employer in team size, FoxPro, and "version management". I found it untenable to continue to work there because of the sheer technical debt that was incurred. I spent more time on phone support than development and I took flack for long development cycles. My advice, use version control even without his buy in.

Comment: There are good answers here.  I would highly recommend learning a tool such as git rather than subversion.  I cannot speak for the myriad other tools, but I have used both of these tools.  Git does a better job of interfacing with outside "change management" like the Boss' Submissions System.  Subversion tends to function better when it is unfettered by other systems. (If others have a different opinion, feel free to disagree)

Comment: The answers here are all good - I just want to add one thing: by using git/hg/svn yourself, you can really easily satisfy your boss' insane requirements! Just use the tool to generate the diff status and format as his UPDATE.NFO file!

Comment: "Due to variations in geographical legal requirements, the decision was made (before I was hired) to fork the app into 7 completely separate directories for each version." - I would like to point out that even source control will only slightly mitigate this disaster in the making. Keeping 7 versions with slight variations in sync is far harder than any complexity introduced even by littering the code with conditionals. And there are design patterns that are far better than having conditionals all over the place.

Comment: What do you think will happen when your boss finds out that you copied his e-mails into the internet where a lot of strangers are now telling you that he's a complete idiot?

Comment: my 50 cents: DON'T USE SVN, IT IS OBSOLETE AND IS PHASED OUT. Don't use SCMs with no future, like cvs, svn, or the SCMs already lost the competition to git, like bazaar, fossil and hg. If you want a mature SCM with lot of software around it, just use git. If you want adventures, try something new like pijul (and prepare yourself to do everything via CLI instead of GUI then), but that new must have a killer feature (like commit reordering in pijul, or maybe being AST-based on some non-existent VCS) and must have the potential to replace git.

Comment: I understand your desire to use version control, but are you planning to do this, only for the source code, or also for the binaries? Oh, and by the way: don't miss Christian Handl's comment: when you "copy" something "directly" from your company's information, don't forget to replace some words in order not to have exact copies.

Answer (score 35):

Don't ask him. Don't tell him. **Show him.**

Install svn, or git, or whatever you like on some extra machine. Practice using it yourself until you feel comfortable not just using it, but explaining it. If you're going to make him comfortable with your new system, you'll need to be more than comfortable with it yourself. You'll need to be able to help him recover easily when he screws up a merge or checks something into the wrong place.

When you're ready, show him exactly what you're talking about. Show him that it doesn't "make a mess" of anything. Point out that it doesn't just let you retrieve any previous version of your code with ease, it also makes it possible to know exactly what changed between any two versions.

Point out that if anything ever happens to the server (serious bug, virus, hacker, disk crash...) **you'll both look like heros** if you can instantly reconstruct the necessary version. Point out, too, that you'll look twice as good if you're able to produce *any* version on demand. Search your old e-mail and compile a list of problems you've had over the past year that you could have avoided with version control.

Give him a cheat sheet that will **make it easy for him** to use your version control system.

Finally, **suggest some options** but **leave the decision to him**. Should you set up your own server, or use one of [the many hosted services](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/)? Should you use svn, git, or something else? Should you migrate all seven projects to the system, or try it with one or two at first?

Comment: +1 for "don't tell, show (after practice)"

Comment: But as someone said, DO use it for your own copy

Comment: +1 for `search your old e-mail and compile a list of problems you've had over the past year that you could have avoided with version control.`

Comment: Additionally, showing might be easier if there's something to show. I'd advise to use something with a GUI, like e.g. [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) for git. That way it looks way less intimidating, it's easier to learn, nobody has to fear messing up the whole system with a little typo and it pretty much _already is_ a graphical version of the cheat sheet you mention.

Answer (score 28):

Benefits of source control go far beyond allowing multiple developers to work on a single piece of code. Eric Sink, the founder of [SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/company/index.html), lists a few compelling reasons to [use source control as a sole developer](http://www.ericsink.com/item_10134.html):

```
- It's an undo mechanism.
- It's a historical archive.
- It's a reference point for diff.
- It's a backup.
- It's a journal of my progress. 
- It's a server.
```

Eric also happens to have a very nice beginners' [Source Control How-to](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html). There is a free online [Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com/) available by Joel Spolsky, Mercurial is a popular distributed version control system.

As the next step I suggest you to start using source control locally on your machine, as a sole developer. Very soon your boss will notice that you're capable of sheer magic, like telling within minutes, if not seconds, how far back a super-critical bug goes and then you would tell him precisely which customer accounts were affected and need fixing before all hell breaks loose. Or being able to undo any changes CEO disapproves of super fast.

And finally before you try to convince your boss you may want to delve into the topic of [objection-handling](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=handling%20objections). It's 101 of sales.

If unsuccessful - move on as soon as practically possible, not much point in wasting your time tilting at windmills.

Comment: +1 for the Eric Sink article. +1 for suggesting hg. git is all the rage but the question clearly states that op is a beginner in source control and hg is a little bit easier to get into than git. +1 for the hg tutorial. +1 for providing a sales oriented reference, that's how you best deal with Pointy-haired Bosses (-0.5 for that being a google search link). +1 for the Don Quixote reference. This is the kind of answer that makes me want to create duplicate accounts so I can upvote more than once.

Comment: This answer basically says it all. Just one more reason why you should use source control on your own: if and when you do move on, having had some experience with source control will look good on your resume. Not having any such experience will not look good.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, using source control, even if only for you, is totally worthwhile. Git, for instance, works really well for a standalone developer and allows you to do things such as branch and merge (with the lowest possible cost) and version your changes as you go.

SVN - or any version control system, really - allows you to do this too, but merging is a bit more problematic.

Comment: I agree with the use of Git. I use it for projects, even if I'm the ONLY developer.

Comment: I'm starting to as well.  I wouldn't with SVN...but with Git, it's so easy to create and manage a repo without even dealing with a server, that it's getting harder to justify *not* saying `git init` the second you start working on something.

Comment: without the right `.gitignore` a git repo is basically useless. That's the only thing that you have to have in place aside from `git init`

Comment: "_but merging is a bit more problematic_" - if OP only uses it himself, there's not gonna be a lot of merging, is there? Merging back his own feature branch into his own master maybe, but any code he receives from his boss would rather go in a new commit, no? I have no experience with SVN though, only git.

Comment: “There’s not gonna be a lot of merging” until there is. Any project, even if it’s a hobby project, will eventually require the dev team (which could be one person) to work on two things at once. Then you have to merge, and at some point you will encounter merge conflicts.

Answer (score 5):

> If I can't convince him, would there be any point to me using it only for myself?

Yes.  There's benefit to using it just for yourself.  You get change history so you can see what's different.

No.  There's no benefit because your boss has doomed your project to lots of pointless rework because they fouled things up.

Comment: It's not just that you can see what's different, you can switch between new version and any old version within two seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend as mentioned before the use of git, the reason #1 is because any VCS is a safety net in case of disaster. Look for the “In case of fire: git commit, git push, leave the building” sticker. The code may be stored somewhere else, but no in a laptop that can break down, be stolen or whatever... even a local network server is not the safest place for something as valuable as code.

Number 2. Traceability of changes, who did what, when, etc... Merges, Undo.
Number 3. Diff the magical tool for #2 and many more cases.
Number 4. Branches
Number 5. Tagging versions, releases, etc..

You may find more information about one of the most common git workflows here: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I know that using git can be intimidating at first, but it’s a good investment for a skill, and a must have for any development team.

About your issue with text case, avoid using Tortoise, I know most people use it as a GUI for git, as it was very common for SVN, so it may be first choice, instead use command line, or a another GUI like github desktop or the SourceTree from Atlasian.